# Faster way for .isin() to extract conditional rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I wrote code that looks for all 'Contact' (grouped by Name) that is done via email. It's done with .isin(), then, extracts the True booleans to create a new dataframe. **Is there a faster and simpler way for doing this?**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['adam','ben','ben','ben','adam','adam','adam'],
                   'Date':['2014-06-01 18:47:05.069722','2014-06-01 18:47:05.069722','2014-06-30 13:47:05.069722',
                      '2013-06-01 18:47:05.069722','2014-01-01 18:47:05.06972','2014-06-01 18:47:05.06972',
                      '2014-06-02 18:47:05.06972'], 
                   'Contact':['phone','email','email','email','email','email','Nan']})
```

"""Pull only those rows where form of Contact is 'email', to construct new dataframe"""

```
 emails = df.groupby('Name')['Contact'].apply(lambda i: i.isin(['email']))
 a = list(np.where(email))  #create list of indices of True booleans 
 lst = a[0]
 df = df.iloc[lst, :] #new dataframe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could in fact use this with `loc` and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

```
df = df.loc[df.Contact == "email"]
```

or even a bit faster using [str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) as follows: as mentionned by @Sergey Bushmanov

```
df = df.loc[df.Contact.str.contains("email")]
```

which gives the exact same output, quite faster if you're using big set of data and a lost simpler i believe.

`Vectorized` methods are always faster than `apply`.

you could also refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-iterrows-have-performance-issues/24871316#24871316) for more information about speed and performance of pandas methods.

other documentation about [enhancing performance](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html#vectorize).

Comment: Thank you Rayhane. This is definitely a lot cleaner and quicker. I appreciate it. 

What does Vectorized methods mean? Why is .loc[] called vectorized?

Comment: @AdamSchroeder, you're welcome, also you'll see i added another documentation if you're interested. vectorized methods are basically those that do not require you to loop over the rows explicitly but will apply on all of them automatically. the documentation I provided is a lot more detailed i strongly recommend checking them

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness:

```
df = df.loc[df.Contact.str.contains("email")]
```

Runtime:

```
%timeit df.loc[df.Contact.str.contains("email")]
646 µs ± 20 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df.loc[df.Contact == "email"]
750 µs ± 19.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

PS

`str` methods for `string` manipulations are usually optimized for dealing with text. For big DF's, the time difference will be even bigger.

Comment: Thank you Sergey I'll use .str then.